# Criar variáveis com dados da database?

Tags: php, mysql

Eu gostaria de ter um `while` de uma `query`e que vá buscar os dados e crie 3 variáveis à parte com essas informações. Por exemplo:

```
$sel_exclui=mysql_query("SELECT * from tabela order by id DESC LIMIT 0,3");
```

Pensei em usar `mysql_fetch_array` mas não sei bem usar. Se for essa a solução, como posso fazer?

Eu sei que mysql está `deprecated` mas este projeto estava a ser feito por outra pessoa e eu tomei posse do projeto e para não ter de alterar tudo, tenho trabalhado com ele.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para pegar os 3 resultados é simples:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * from tabela order by id DESC LIMIT 0,3");
$itens = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
    $itens[$row['id']] = array($row['name'], $row['outro_campo']);   
}
```

Coloquei id e nome como exemplo, no lugar de id e nome são os campos da sua tabela.

Comment: Mas eu gostaria de guardar esses valores em variàveis para usar depois fora do `while`

Comment: Fiz a alteração, é só atribuir nas variáveis

Comment: Mas assim a variável vai ser sempre reposta certo?

Comment: desta forma você pode construir um array

Comment: Fiz como disse, resultou mas eu fiz print_r do array e aparece-me assim

`Array ( [68] => Array ( [0] => 68 ) [67] => Array ( [0] => 67 ) [66] => Array ( [0] => 66 ) )`

Comment: Você tem que colocar o 'id', 'nome' e 'outro_campo' de acordo com o seu banco, para saber o que esta chegando da um print_r no $row.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66026/discussion-between-wictor-chaves-and-i-like-trains).

Comment: Problema resolvido :)

Answer (score 2):

Normalmente faço assim:

```
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($sel_exclui)) 
{
   $campo_01 = $row['campo_01'];
   $campo_02 = $row['campo_02'];
   $campo_03 = $row['campo_03'];
}
```

Onde a variável `$campo_01` recebe da tabela o valor do `campo_01`, e assim ocorre o mesmo para as variáveis `$campo_02` e `$campo_03`.

Note que é um `while`, então se o resultado do `select` contiver mais de uma linha, os valores guardados nas variáveis serão sempre do **último registro** do select.